# MySQL multiple queries with limit 1, will UNION improve speed?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, union

I have 3 queries ending in limit 1 from a database of around 170,000 records.

Is there any difference if I run these 3 queries separately or will combining all 3 by using UNION improve the speed? Currently the query is slow to return the results.

So the end result will return 3 records from the database.

My current queries:

```
select * from table where cat = '%1%' and brand like '%example%' limit 1;
select * from table where cat = '%2%' and brand like '%example2%' limit 1;
select * from table where cat = '%3%' and brand like '%example3%' limit 1;
```

With UNION:

```
(select * from table where cat = '%1%' and brand like '%example%' limit 1) UNION     (select * from table where cat = '%2%' and brand like '%example2%' limit 1) UNION (select *     from table where cat = '%3%' and brand like '%example3%' limit 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`union` will execute all three queries, and then attempt to remove duplicates from them, so it will almost certainly **decrease** performance. Using `union all` instead of running three separate queries may slightly improve performance, as it will save the back-and-forth of three independent executions.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything else I can do to speed up the query time?